# Xerces JAR causing exception

Tags: java, dom, sax, xerces

Facing a strange issue with Xerces jars. I migrated my code into a different workspace. There was a portion of the code that used org.w3c.dom XML classes. Now that i migrated the code, the same code is throwing exceptions.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

But when i debug it the objects created are of type:

```
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
```

Not sure where the xerces classes came into the picture. And this is causing the code to fail.

Updating with the code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
Document document = builder.parse(inputSource);

String grade = "A";
NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("student");
if (!routeLimit.equals("")) {
    Text gradeText = document.createTextNode(grade);
    Element gradeTag = document.createElement("grade");
    gradeTag .appendChild(gradeText);
    nodes.item(0).appendChild(gradeTag);
}
```

The line:
    nodes.item(0).appendChild(gradeTag);

Throws a null pointer exception.

Also, when i debug the code, the value of the document variable [#document: null], I checked this site and saw many people facing the same issue. But there were very few concrete answers.

Comment: Is it possible to know what exactly is the exception that is thrown so far? `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl` is implementing `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`, so the imports are not the root of your exception.

Comment: Its a null pointer exception.

Comment: Check the dependencies in your old workspace. Are you sure that you used the same version of xerces there or maybe some other implementation of XML classes? I once had a similar problem after switching from Xerces to Saxon.

Comment: Well its been a while since i checked this portion of the code, but i do remember the when i did the code, the objects created were different than what it is now. It would be great if you can give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the XML namespace.

I had to set the:

```
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

and then fetch the node using:

```
NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("ml:student");
```

Kind of stumbled upon the solution. the same code worked before, without the namespace.